# Position of Preposition phrases

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-order

Do all the following three sentences mean the same? Where should I put the preposition phrase.

1- **In India**, people love to eat mangoes.

2- People **in India** love to eat mangoes.

3- People love to eat mangoes **in India.**

4 - Farmers are protesting **in India.**

5 - Farmers **in India** are protesting.

6 - **In India**, farmers are protesting.

Comment: #3 has a way different meaning from #1 and #2...and #4 is very different to #5 and #6. Also, #1 and #6 are different to the rest.

Comment: They can all report on many of the same situations, but they're ambiguous. That is, each has more than one single meaning. So you can't say whether they "mean the same" or not.